# React-admin custom routes: Property noLayout does not exist on type Route

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-admin

I'm trying to make a forgot password page, which need to be rendered without the layout. I'm following the example in documentation, Admin page, customRoutes section and adapting it to Typescript. Without the noLayout property, the route is rendering, but within the layout. The problem arises when adding noLayout to the route:

Property 'noLayout' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<{}, "/forgot-password">> & Readonly<RouteProps<"/forgot-password", {}> & OmitNative<...>> & Readonly<...>'.

I realized that I'm using a Route component from react-router-dom implementing RouterProps and the property noLayout is declared in CustomRoute (extending RouterProps). The Admin's customRoutes property is waiting for an array of something implementing CustomRoutes interface, but instead I'm providing an array of Routes (like it is in the docs)

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Here is my App.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import portugueseMessages from '@henriko/ra-language-portuguese'
import polyglotI18nProvider from 'ra-i18n-polyglot'

import dataProvider from './providers/dataProvider'
import authProvider from './providers/authProvider'
import Layout from './layout/Layout'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard'
import ForgotPassword from './pages/ForgotPassword'

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(() => portugueseMessages, 'pt')

  return (
    <Admin
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
      authProvider={authProvider}
      i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
      layout={Layout}
      loginPage={Login}
      customRoutes={[
        <Route
          key="forgot-password"
          path="/forgot-password"
          component={ForgotPassword}
          exact
          noLayout
        />
      ]}
    >
      <Resource {...Dashboard} />
    </Admin>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-admin exposes a `CustomRoute` type that you can use in this case:

```
import { CustomRoute } from 'react-admin';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(() => portugueseMessages, 'pt')

  return (
    <Admin
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
      authProvider={authProvider}
      i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
      layout={Layout}
      loginPage={Login}
      customRoutes={[
-       <Route
+       <Route<CustomRoute>
          key="forgot-password"
          path="/forgot-password"
          component={ForgotPassword}
          exact
          noLayout
        />
      ]}
    >
      <Resource {...Dashboard} />
    </Admin>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this still work with react router v6? I'm getting an error for `Route`: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)

Comment: To use react-router v6, you'll need react-admin v4